# Update query for instance variable

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4

With some help I have now got params being passed to a method in my controller. What I am now stuck on is how to use that method and assign it to my instance variable.

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController

def rehome
  @animals = Animal.animals_rehome.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.js
    end
 end

def rehomed
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js {render :json => Animal.where(animal_type: params[:animal_type]) }
 end
end
```

The params are updated with the following ajax post

```
$('select.btn').on('change', function() {
  var animal_type = $('#animalType option:selected').text();
  var animal_town = $('#animalTown option:selected').text();

  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/public/rehomed',
    data: {
     animal_type: animal_type,
   },
    success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
    }
    });
  });
```

What I want to achieve is that on initial page load use

```
def rehome
 @animals = Animal.animals_rehome.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
end
```

but then when selecting my filters via the select dropdown menu I want

```
 def rehome
  @animals = rehomed.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
 end
```

But I'm not sure how to set this out.

### Edit

My setup now looks like

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :default_animal

def rehome
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
  end
end


def rehomed
 conditions = {}
 conditions.merge!(animal_type: params[:animal_type]) if params[:animal_type].present?
 conditions.merge!(rehomed: params[:rehomed]) if params[:rehomed].present?
 conditions.merge!(users: {town: params[:animal_town]}) if params[:animal_town].present?

 @animals = Animal.joins(:user).where(conditions)

  respond_to do |format|
   format.js { render json: @animals }
  end
end


private

def default_animal
  @animals = Animal.animals_rehome.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
end

end
```

My ajax request sends the correct parameters to build the the @animals query each time the dropdowns are updated in the view and what I would like to achieve is that the results of the new query to be loaded onto the page in align with the will_paginate structure if that's at all possible.

```
   $('select.btn').on('change', function() {
    var animal_type = $('#animalType option:selected').text();
    var animal_town = $('#animalTown option:selected').text();
    var data_send = { animal_type: animal_type, animal_town: animal_town, rehomed: false}


   if(animal_type == 'All') {
    data_send = {animal_town: animal_town, rehomed: false}
   }
  if(animal_town == 'All') {
   data_send = {animal_type: animal_type, rehomed: false}
  }

  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/public/rehomed',
    data: data_send,
     success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
     }
  });
 });
```

View `rehome.html.erb`

```
 <div class="all_animals">
  <%= render @animals %> # this is in a partial called _animal.html.erb
 </div>

 <div id="infinite-scrolling">
   <%= will_paginate @animals %>
 </div>
```

`rehome.js.erb`

```
$('.all_animals').append('<%= j render @animals %>');
 <% if @animals.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @animals %>');
 <% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('.pagination').remove();
```

Comment: Instance variables are not stored between requests. You'll have to recreate state for each request. To do this, you'll need to preserve auxilliary data (current page number or animal type, for example). Normally this is done via query string.

Comment: would you be able to provide an example of what you mean please, not quite understanding your explanation

Comment: What he means is you need to create a new request each time you want to show an updated values queried in `@animals` from rehomed, one way to do is to update the view/HTML in jQuery's `success` callback.

Comment: i wouldnt even know where to begin on that, do you know of any literature that gives an example..

Comment: First, the default_animal is being called before rehomed is called, meaning the `@animals` is already being set. Then you are overriding its value in the rehomed action `@animals = Animal.joins(:user).where(conditions)` . I mean, maybe you dont need the filter to be called in rehomed. Not very sure how to do it but it would be easier if you would render partial. Render the rehome layout in the rehomed action and just insert that view in the body of your html when the ajax request returns. It would automatically change the pagination. `@animals` must be set in rehomed with pagination

Comment: i have updated my question with my view so you can see how im calling my results with ajax and will_paginate... from what you have advised me this should work but looking at my `rehome.js.erb` file, should i enclose this in `$('select.btn').on('change', function()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use before_filter

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :filter_method

    def rehome
        respond_to do |format|
         format.html
         format.js
        end
     end

    def rehomed
      respond_to do |format|
       format.js {render :json => @animals.where(animal_type: params[:animal_type]) }
     end

    private
    def filter_method
      @animals = Animal.animals_rehome.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
    end
end
```

You need params[:page] and params[:animal_type] for the rehomed action

more on [before_filter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter)

Comment: so would i call the before_filter on rehome action only and then rehomed would be `@animals.where(:page => params[:page], animal_type: params[:animal_type])`

Comment: in the code above, the before_filter is called before every action and it has to be like that in order to retrieve the value of the '@animals 'instance variable. Just as @sergio said in the comment "Instance variables are not stored between requests. You'll have to recreate state for each request ...." 
Every action happens in a single request. A request to your rehomed action does not request the rehome action, but they both use the before_filter to not repeat yourself (DRY)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. what i still get trouble with though is as i am using will_paginate with an infinite scroll implementation,  when searching for say 'cats' in 'cardiff', all the params are passed correctly but when i scroll down the page, it defaults back to the original filter method assignment of @animals (i.e it shows all the animals as per the scope of animals_rehome)

Comment: could you update your question with the current state of your code? 

This is not related to the question but I like to point out that you should use action names like index, show, edit, update, and destroy since it makes it easier to read and it is a standard for rails.

I also suggest you try [Agile Web Development With Rails Book](https://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4)
:)

Comment: thank you for the book suggestion, appreciated.. I know about CRUD, what im doing here isn't CRUD related.. I will update my question though and hopefully you will be able to assist